# Ruby SerialPort doesn't seem to initialize

Tags: ruby

I'm working with the Ruby 1.8.7 SerialPort gem to communicate with an AVR through a FTDI232 USB-to-Serial converter. I seem to be having an issue with SerialPort initializing a new SerialPort.

What I've discovered is when I open the connection with either PuTTY on Windows or Minicom on Linux and send commands this way, everything works as it should.

I've also noticed that after closing PuTTY/Minicom, my code works fine. Therefore I'm led to believe that something isn't working right with how the SerialPort gem initializes the serial connection.

Has anyone else experience this issue or have any ideas as to how to fix it?

EDIT:
Here's a code sample. 
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'serialport'

```
sp = SerialPort.new("COM5", 115200)
sp.print("A\r")
data = sp.readline("\r\n")
puts data
sp.close
```

This code should open a connection and send a character indicating the type of data wanted from my AVR. It then waits for the data to be transmitted back, and prints it to the screen.

When my device is connected initially the code just hangs on read, but after stopping the script, opening a connection with PuTTY, closing the PuTTY connection the script does exactly what it is supposed to.

Comment: Perhaps only one process can control the serial port at a time?

Comment: I'm not opening them at the same time. If I unplug the cable then reconnect, my code will not work. If I open a connection using PuTTY/Minicom, then close the connection then run my ruby code again, my ruby code works exactly as it is supposed to. Sorry, I re-read my post and understand the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, only one process can connect to a serial port at a time.  I'm not sure about Linux.

Make sure you are setting the baud rate correctly in your code.

If you continue to have trouble, post some really simple example code, along with a description of the expected behavior and the actual behavior.

Comment: I'm not trying to control the serial port with more than one process. If I disconnect the cable, reconnect and run my Ruby code it hangs. If I stop my code, open a connection with PuTTY, close the PuTTY connection, then run my Ruby code again, my Ruby code works exactly as it should.

Comment: Also I've double checked that the baud rate is set appropriately.

Comment: Then post some really simple example code, along with a description of the expected behavior and the actual behavior.

Comment: I added some sample code, if you have a chance to take a look at it I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I've solved my issue. Adding a read_timeout seems to have fixed it.

```
sp = SerialPort.new("COM5", 115200)
sp.read_timeout = 1500
```

Using PuTTY/Minicom must have some how set this up and left it after close.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue on Linux debian 3.1.0-1-amd64.

The issue was related to a bug introduced in ftdi_sio kernel module (google for "Fix Corruption issue in USB ftdi driver ftdi_sio.c").

I have applied the patch (see https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/2/1/574) rebuilding the module ftdi_sio.ko and the problem is now solved.

1. Get kernel source  linux-3.1.10.tar.bz2 (my actual kernel is  3.1.0-1-amd64).
2. Apply patch
3. Recompile module (example how to do it in http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html)
4. Backup original module in 
   /lib/modules/3.1.0-1-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.ko 
   and replace it with new one.
5. Reboot

*A quick and dirty workaround can be also to force a change in the baudrate (doesn't not require to recompile the kernel module):*

```
sp = SerialPort.new("/dev/ttyUSB0")
sp.baud=300 #value which is not often used
sp.baud=9600
```

...

sp.